# Including tests done at a commercial lab in a manuscript

Tags: journals, acknowledgement, experiment-design

In the course of an experimental study, I sent a few samples for testing at a commercial lab. By commercial, I mean that they provide standardized testing services for a fee, and are not engaged in research or development. These tests are a paid service rather than a collaboration.

The tests are routine engineering tests, generally used to qualify materials. I would like to include some of these test results in an upcoming manuscript, which contains several other experiments done at my institute. What is the appropriate procedure for using these results?

I'm considering:

(a) Include them with the other experimental procedures, specifying the standard that was followed for the tests. This would include all the details needed to reproduce the tests, without mentioning the specific lab where they were carried out.

(b) In addition to (a), mention the lab in the acknowledgements. I doubt this will benefit the lab in any way, but if its more ethically appropriate, I'd pick it. This is also what we'd do for tests done at another research/academic lab.

(c) Mention in the 'Methods' section itself that these tests were carried out at a commercial facility. This seems a bit jarring and awkward to me, and I've not seen it anywhere (yet).

Better suggestions are most welcome, examples (if available) would be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your paper, you need to describe all the methods you used. One of the methods you used was to send samples for processing at a commercial lab. This is very common, I'm surprised you haven't encountered it before.

While you do not need to lay out all of their SOPs and specific sources of their reagents, you at **minimum** need to state the commercial lab you sent the samples to (typically by name, city, and country and any appropriate intermediate stages like US state) and the tests they performed. Also good to include *some* of the methodological details they used if they are not completely standard as these may change.

No need to put them in an acknowledgment.

Comment: Glad I asked! For my understanding, what is the rationale for mentioning lab location/specifics, given that these such are meant to be location/operator independent?

Comment: @AppliedAcademic Because they're not independent. It's also typical to mention manufacturers/sources of ingredients used in experiments, etc. Basically, if you didn't personally verify that a certain reagent is what you say it is, you point to the responsible party who did. When you send something to an outside lab, you can't vouch for what they send back but they can. It lets someone reading your paper replicate your result by going to the same lab, or decide how much they want to trust your results based on who you've sent the work to.

Comment: Same goes for, say, authors of statistics software you use to analyze data.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Unless it's absolutely critical, providing vendor info for the lab, and then citing their certifications, is enough.  That's what standards are for.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Disagree with that in general - you should provide enough information to reproduce. Standards are often not, and change over time.

Comment: @BryanKrause They may change over time, but one can *always* see what they were at any given time, especially with proper citation.  There are hundreds of thousands of published case studies where laboratory values are given, with no methods offered, other than a vague assumption that the clinical labs have been certified to relevant clinical standards.  Because of these standards, a red blood cell count is a red blood cell count regardless if it was done by a tech looking through a microscope or a Coulter-counter, and urine pH is urine pH, whether done by a tech with a dipstick or a pH meter.

Comment: @ScottSeidman For most of the laboratory measurements used in my field there is no such level of standard. Anything outside actual clinically-used diagnostics. Your best bet would be to ask for the company's SOPs at the time, which they may have access to, but also may not be easily available if the company has closed/purchased/changed names. And, no, I disagree, a "red blood cell count" is not a "red blood cell count" regardless. Sample preparation and storage and everything else can have impacts on lab results.

Comment: @BryanKrause -- I'd rather avoid hypotheticals.  Many researches do laboratory testing that one simply cannot do in a commercial lab.  Since this OP is specifically reporting "routine engineering tests", there are *very likely* very sound standards from ISO, ASE, ASTM, ....  Prep and storage are issues, but once in a certified lab, all handling and storage will comply with ISO 15189.  If any of the pre-lab prep is important, that would go in any pub, but is outside the scope of the question.  As an aside, testing to an FDA-recognized standard is sufficient for premarket clearance applications

Comment: @ScottSeidman As I wrote in my answer, "Also good to include some of the methodological details they used if they are not completely standard as these may change."

Comment: Also, unless I'm missing something, these standards say nothing about how tests are actually performed.

Comment: Testing standards are usually extremely specific about methods.  While you can't see the standards, see https://www.admet.com/testing-applications/testing-standards/ and look at the titles.  Sorry I'm perpetuating over this, but engineers live and die by standards.  With respect to FDA, and other regulatory agencies, you can properly use standards and get your premarket devices through the process in finite time and costs, or subject yourself to unnecessary surprises and very expensive delays.  Teaching proper use of standards is required for accreditation of engineering departments.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Most people doing biomedical research are not submitting to FDA or any regulatory agency and are not engineers. I know OP is likely not in those research fields, but the title of their question is more general, so I provided a more general answer. If, indeed, there are processing steps that vary, my answer points out that they need to explain this in their methods rather than just referring to the commercial lab doing the test.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend citing the lab as a vendor, and then listing and citing any quality assurance standards the lab complies to, such as ISO9001 (or ISO 15189, for clinical labs).  This way, you're off the hook entirely for describing the commercial lab's methods.

Answer (score 1):

All of what you describe seems completely appropriate. In the methods section you should probably say why you use the lab. Independent tests according to a well-defined standard can be a plus in your methodology, lessening any hint of bias.

For the second point, I think it is more of an etiquette concern than, strictly, an ethical one, since the lab gets paid and isn't a "research  collaborator". But, it is good to do in any case.